# backspace not working in bash restricted mode

Tags: linux, bash

I am facing a problem with backspace in bash when used in restricted mode. I have already googled through lots of things, nothing worked or matching scenario am facing.

On pressing backspace, cursor is moving forward by one white space, but internally actually it's deleting the previous letter, i.e. on pressing "enter" it actually works but not visible on screen.

Example: command "ls backspace backspace", don't list anything (as expected) but on screen ls is visible after 2 backspaces and extra 2 white spaces are appended.

Looking forward for helpful suggestions. :)

Thanks in advance !! :)

Below is the piece of patch i used to chroot my bash.
Please have look and notify me if something is wrong here.

file: shell.c: @@ -384,6 +387,30 @@

```
+  if (getcwd(pwd,sizeof(pwd)) != pwd )
+        {
+                return -1;
+        }
+        /* chroot to mount point path */
+        if( !(chroot(chroot_dir)))
+        {
+                seteuid(getuid());
+                setegid(getgid());
+                /* On successful to chroot env invoke bash prompt */ 
+                if(! chdir(pwd))
+                {
+                        if(execlp("/rbin/bash","/rbin/bash","--restricted",NULL))
+                        {
+                        }
+                }
+                else
+                {
+                        chdir("/");
+                        if(execlp("/rbin/bash","/rbin/bash","--restricted",NULL))
+                        { 
+                        }
+                }
+        }
```

Comment: Is this in the console or in a terminal emulator. If it is a terminal emulator, this could be settings related.

Comment: it's normal bash only with certain extra patches introduced by me. the same is working with other environment where OS version is different (older OS version)

Answer (score 0):

Try using Backspace with Shift key, It should work.

If pressing backspace is printing a character, then you can use stty to change terminal settings like this: `stty erase backspace_character` where backspace_character is the character you get while pressing backspace.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I have restricted stty command in my bash because i don't want it in my restricted bash mode, for security reasons. Also this solution looks more like a workaround, it'll not fix actual root cause.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `emacs` command

for **shell terminal** you can hit command as below

```
set -o emacs
```

for **vi editor** you can hit command as below

```
set -o vi
```

Comment: set -o emacs is not helpful.